# Which achievements are missable if sharing Skylanders between multiple profiles?

Tags: achievements, skylanders

Since purchasing *Skylanders* with my son and realizing you [can't have different profiles on each character](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46770/how-to-have-different-game-data-profiles-in-skylander), I've also noticed some achievements are not unlocking depending on who first used the Skylander and who it is tied to. In short, all the Skylanders appears to be tied to my profile, but it's preventing some achievements from unlocking on my son's profile.

They aren't just the achievements described with (primary profile), as most have unlocked for both of us while playing separately. So far I've noticed that the following achievements won't unlock once a Skylander is tied to someone:

**Fashion Stylist** - Have your Skylander equip a hat for the first time. (primary profile)

**Hello!! Skylander** - The first time you put your Skylander on the Portal of Power. (primary profile)

What other achievements are tied to a Skylander unlocked by a specific person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the ones you mentioned, the following achievements may give you trouble..

I Love Shopping - Buy first Upgrade - if all of the Skylanders already have one+ upgrade

Climb to the Top - Level Up to 10 - If all Skylanders are already at 10

True Portal Master - all other Achievements  - obviously, if you can't get any of the others

Note that you can reset a Skylander to level 1, or transfer it to someone else.  Look under the Manage option in the Menu.

Comment: Do you happen to know if 2 people level up a single character to Level 10, will that affect Climb to the Top? Will it not pop for both, only for the original owner, or whoever is playing the character at Level 10?

Comment: Whoever is playing with it when it hits level 10.  You. for instance, could play it for 9 levels, but if your son is playing it at that moment, he gets the achievement.  However, notice that if you are playing co-op, and you are primary profile, then you get the achievement.  My son and I had the same situation.  However, he had a favorite, and I stuck with one through most levels until I got the achievement.  We would also alternate as the primary profile so that each person reaped the rewards.

Answer (score -1):

To get 100% percent in the game, you can both take ownership of all the Skylanders you have.

Comment: That doesn't necessarily answer the question though. Doozer Blake was asking what achievements were missing, but if it's possible to not miss out on any achievements, your answer doesn't exactly say either. How would one take ownership of all Skylanders? What's the process?